# How is Phosphorus made in in stars?

Tags: star, the-sun, supernova, red-giant, astrochemistry

What elements are required to fuse into phosphorus in a star. Can someone give me a step by step process please e.g

> 4 hydrogen nuclei fuse into one helium nuclei and then 3 helium nuclei
>   fuse into carbon inside a red giant etc.
>
> 1H x 4 = 1HE, 1HE x 3 = 1C etc.

Comment: See https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/18535/are-sulfur-and-phosphorus-also-created-in-the-nucleosynthesis-of-big-stars

Comment: @RobJeffries The [ArXiv preprint](https://arxiv.org/abs/1112.3824) linked there says "There is only one
single stable isotope of P, 31P, which is thought to be formed by
neutron capture on 29Si and 30Si in massive stars." and so would the answer be 28Si (via alpha process) followed by a total of three neutron captures and a beta decay? Or is is more complicated?

Comment: Couldn't find this with a minimal Googlification?   got tons of clean hits with  https://www.google.com/search?q=phosphorus+production+in+star&rlz=1C1GGRV_enUS749US750&oq=phosphorus+production+in+star&aqs=chrome..69i57.7352j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Comment: @CarlWitthoft never underestimate the nature of a well written Stack Exchange answer, it's way more than just a collection of internet "hits".

Comment: Sounds like a chemistry/physics quesiton. It's about atomic fusion not stars.

Comment: its about stars aswell because i want to know how the universe created phospherous.